# how to access dropdown selection in Cypress, get error: element is detached from the DOM

Tags: css, cypress

I am trying to select a dropdown item using Cypress. When i use the Cypress's Open Selector Playground, and point at the Web Element, i get cy.get('.Dropdown-placeholder').type('Name')

I get an error:

```
CypressError
Timed out retrying: cy.type() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.

<div class="Dropdown-placeholder"></div>

Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them.

The previous command that ran was:

  > cy.get()

This DOM element likely became detached somewhere between the previous and current command.

Common situations why this happens:
  - Your JS framework re-rendered asynchronously
  - Your app code reacted to an event firing and removed the element

You typically need to re-query for the element or add 'guards' which delay Cypress from running new commands.Learn more
```

and when i try to get the CSS Selector for the actual Entry, i get:
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > #Question > .Dropdown-root > .Dropdown-control > .Dropdown-placeholder')

when i try `cy.get('.Dropdown-placeholder').focus().type('Name')`
I get Error:

```
cy.focus() can only be called on a valid focusable element. Your subject is a: <div class="Dropdown-placeholder"></div>
```

and for: `cy.get('.Dropdown-placeholder').click().type('Name')`
i get error:

```
CypressError
Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.

<div class="Dropdown-placeholder"></div>

Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them.

The previous command that ran was:

  > cy.get()

This DOM element likely became detached somewhere between the previous and current command.

Common situations why this happens:
  - Your JS framework re-rendered asynchronously
  - Your app code reacted to an event firing and removed the element

You typically need to re-query for the element or add 'guards' which delay Cypress from running new commands.Learn more
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="Dropdown-root module-Questions-module-dropDownContainer--2bcD7--"><div class="Dropdown-control" aria-haspopup="listbox"><div class="Dropdown-placeholder is-selected">Name</div><div class="Dropdown-arrow-wrapper"><span class="Dropdown-arrow"></span></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you try: `cy.get('.Dropdown-placeholder').focus().type('Name')` or `cy.get('.Dropdown-placeholder').click().type('Name')`?

Comment: @Sree.Bh Tried both options you suggested but got error ( see above in the question )

Comment: I see `.Dropdown-placeholder` element is a `div` and is also not `contenteditable`, are you sure it does not have an internal `input` element where the test can be entered?

Comment: @Sree.Bh I posted the HTML, the div has is-selected with the value, did not see any input tag

Comment: But the dropdown supports `search` by typing a `search text`?

Comment: i get TypeError: cy.get(...).search is not a function, when i use 
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > #Question > .Dropdown-root > .Dropdown-control > .Dropdown-placeholder').search('Name')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216383/discussion-between-sree-bh-and-kamal).

Comment: Could you post the `html`just above the drop down and also full test code

Comment: @soccerway here it is 
<div align="center" class="module-Preconditions-module-questionBox--7l4QC--"><div id="d2fac" class="module-Preconditions-module-number--1SCAR-- module-BrowseBenefits-module-bgBlue--13sWy--">2</div><div id="Question"><span style="position: relative;"><label for="ques1012"><p>Choose the option that best describes your citizenship status:</p></label></span> now as far as test code, please see the discussion

Comment: @Sree.Bh drop down does not support search